# How to disable Win 10 asking me to sign up for OneDrive when I already purchased OneDrive?

Tags: windows, onedrive

This isn't a duplicate of the other answers. I do use OneDrive, and I paid for a premium account. But somehow Win 10 still pops up messages asking me to sign up for OneDrive and use it backup my files.

It shows up periodically in Windows Defender saying I should sign up for OneDrive and use it back up my files. Then it shows up in this Windows Messaging thing telling me the same thing.

I ALREADY bought OneDrive?!! How do I disable this message? This is so crazy.

Comment: How did you buy OneDrive? Did you buy an Office 365 personal/home subscription? Is this part of an Office 365 business subscription? Separate purchase? Did you open OneDrive on your computer and sign in and make sure it is syncing files? Have you tried going to onedrive.live.com and downloading the newest version?

Comment: You can setup your account in OneDrive for OneDrive syncing. If you don't want to use OneDrive and disable this prompt, we can try to disable OneDrive in startup:
Open Task Manager on Windows, click More details, go to Startup tab, right-click the Microsoft OneDrive app, select Disable.

Comment: @Appleoddity so I paid for a 50gb account independently, but then I also bought an office 365 account which I think raised that to a 1tb account. Is this helpful? I thought windows just updated everything automatically.